# Wanting convert old 6502 source code HEX lines to .byte $00 lines

Tags: python, converters, 6502

I need your help please, like the title says, I'm trying to convert a load of source code, and a lot of my old source has a lot of lines of code for an assembler (6502) I no longer can use on Windows.

I can do a lot of search and replaced to change all the opcodes for example !byte into .byte or DCB into .byte, DCW into .word, etc, but I'm stuck when I have lines and lines of HEX codes, that I need to convert into .byte (for example), i.e. let say I have

```
HEX 0000000000000000 
HEX 0000000002000000
```

I want to end up with

```
.byte $00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00
.byte $00,$00,$00,$00,$02,$00,$00,$00
```

Now, if I have only 2 lines of code, I could do this by hand, but when I'm opening up source that has 100's of lines, this would be tedious and take a very long time.

I've thought about Python, I've thought about vb-script even batch scripting, but most of it would involve copying the code into a file, parsing the file with the language (Frankenstein'd code form the internet) and getting a result and loading it back in, I was thinking there must be a way (probably using vbscript, as I use to play with VBA and VB6 back in the day, but I'm too old and rusty to even think about that now) to have two boxes pop up, left box, original copy of HEX, right box .byte output? or even a text input box, I copy and paste into and it gives the result below and then I can just copy and paste back into my source.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the relevant part of the original string to 2-character chunks and use a list comprehension to convert it to the desired format:

```
def convert(s):
  codes = s[4:]
  return ".byte {}".format(",".join("${}".format(codes[i*2:i*2+2]) for i in range(len(codes)//2)))
```

then

```
print(convert("HEX 0123456789ABCDEF"))
```

will print

```
.byte $01,$23,$45,$67,$89,$AB,$CD,$EF
```

You should then be able to use this function in a client application (such as `tkinter`) or in a simple web application (such as `flask`).

Note that you can also find cross-compilers for MOS6502.

Comment: That inner generator expression can be a little bit simplified by not dividing and multiplying with 2 but giving `range()` a step size of 2 instead. And I would use an f-string literal in current Python versions: `(f"${codes[i:i+2]}" for i in range(0,len(codes),2))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an idiomatic python way to group the digits

```
cin = [
    "HEX 0000000000000000",
    "HEX 0000000002000000",
]

cout = [
 '.byte'+ ''.join(
  " ${}".format(''.join(d)) 
  for d in zip(*[iter(c[4:])]*2)
 )
 for c in cin
]
```

Which produces the list

```
[
 '.byte $00 $00 $00 $00 $00 $00 $00 $00',
 '.byte $00 $00 $00 $00 $02 $00 $00 $00'
]
```